# can not comiunicate through ask rf module

Tags: arduino, rf, digital-modulation

I wanted to send data by ardunio through dra886tx(board on the left side )  and receive by another ardunio through dra887rx ; i don't know whats the problem but nothing happen on the receiver board and I'm sure my code are fine because when i replace RF module with actual wire , second arduino receive the signal perfectly ( I'm using virtual wire library programing board )

"sorry for my bad English"
[image]

Comment: "doesn't work", "I don't know what's the problem": This is far too vague to help you at all. You will need to test with an example that is known to work, and then build up a diagnostic statement. With this, it's like going writing a letter to your car mechanic "car doesn't drive. I'm sure I'm steering correctly. Please help."; the car mechanic won't be able to help you based on that, and we can't help you based on your vague question.

Comment: Please see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask if you want to write good questions that conform to the guidelines set up by the community. Please be specific, we aren't at your bench and you need to define the problem clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using something like this: -

[image]

Without antennas!!!!

If you are not using antennas then you are probably assuming you can just feed serial data to the transmit module and get reconstituted perfect serial data from the receive module.

This would be naive.

You need to package your transmissions up with a header/preamble, an address (ideally), data and a checksum (ideally). Then you need to look at your received data (noisy as hell usually when a transmission is not being sent) and recognize the header/preamble then be prepared to recognize the end of the preamble and start of the address/data. Finally, double check the packet with the checksum.

If any inconsistency occurs you should throw the data away and await a re-transmission.

It's never as easy as it seems.

Comment: Dangling wires (from the photo) are not suitable as antennas. [Antenna Theory](http://www.antenna-theory.com/) might get him started, but it's a long road...